# DefinitelyTyped for JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, definitelytyped

I'm trying to write `.d.ts` file for geocomplete jQuery plugin. I'm new to TypeScript. I have added these in my `.d.ts` file:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts"/>

interface GeoOptions {
    map: string,
    mapOptions? : MapOption,
}

interface MapOption extends  GeoOptions {
    zoom : number
}

interface JQuery {
    geocomplete(): JQuery;
    geocomplete(options: GeoOptions): JQuery;
}
```

but I can't initialize plugin like this

```
 $('#geomap').geocomplete(
            {
                map: ".map",
                mapOption: { zoom: 10 },

            });
```

What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the your `interface jQuery`
Since `jQuery` just variable you can not redeclare interface, `jquery.d.ts` file says that, `jQuery` is variable with type `jQueryStatic`. So, we need redeclare `jQueryStatic` instead of `jQuery`.

So, dear friend, I have spent a bit more time for you today and  written exactly what you need)

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts"/>

interface GeoOptions {
    map: string,
    mapOptions? : MapOption,
}

interface MapOption extends GeoOptions {
    zoom : number
}


interface JQueryStatic {
    geocomplete():JQueryStatic;
    geocomplete(options:GeoOptions):JQueryStatic;
}

declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var $: JQueryStatic;

jQuery.geocomplete();
$.geocomplete();
```

Now, it should work perfectly! Enjoy!